# I tried to install NodeJS v14 and broke everything, how to install new version without breaking dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, nodejs

So I found out that for some reason, unlike on Windows you don't just get to chose your NodeJS version. When I install it normally, I get version 10, via command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Tried on two Ubuntu based machines, one Ubuntu 14 (old I know) and one Linux Mint 20.3 Una. Both give me version 10 of nodejs, which is years old. On the nodejs website, I found this [helpful guide that helped me break my system](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#deb) by running this:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

So that did install nodejs 14 as promised, but now nothing that depends on NodeJS can be installed. I get error like this for npm, which is pretty much necessary for working with nodejs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       ...
       ...
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to remove nodejs, but when I install it again I now always get the v14 and the system remains broken.

Can you please help me fix this? Could you also please explain what the command I ran did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove NodeJS completely(package, config)

```
sudo apt purge nodejs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt purge npm
```

Update Package List

```
sudo apt update
```

Note: Check for any `.npm` or `.node` folder in your `home` directory and delete those.

Reinstall NodeJS

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. The bigger issue is apparently that the package for nodejs is not updated any more, so one MUST use the command I used previously in order to use newer versions. That command also installs the npm executable that I was trying to install via APT.

Comment: please use the ▴ symbol to upvote if the answer could solve your problem